# R Package 'ghyp' - fit.ghypuv not converging

Tags: r, error-handling, distribution, data-fitting, convergence

I am using the function fit.ghypuv of pacage ghyp and it does not converge.
It gives me the error code 1( as below) does anyone know what does this error mean and what could cause it?
[error code]

Thank you!